# Finding records with zero or one related records

Tags: mysql

I have a database with two tables: `participants`, and `responses`. Participants can have zero, one, or many responses. Responses can also be incomplete (marked by having NULL in the `ended` timestamp column). Participants could have zero or one incomplete responses.

How do I find all participants who either have no responses, or just one response which is incomplete?

This is the SQL I tried first:

```
SELECT * FROM participants p
LEFT JOIN responses r
  ON p.id = r.id_participant
WHERE r.id IS NULL 
   OR (count(r.id) = 1 AND r.ended IS NULL)
```

I get the error: `Invalid use of group function`

I tried a few variations (e.g. `SELECT *, count(r.id) as numr` etc) but am getting no-where. I believe I need a whole different approach.

Comment: I guess you should use HAVING instead of where

Comment: Does "Participants have many responses, one response is incomplete and the others are completed" belongs to "participants who have one response which is incomplete"?

Comment: @LeoZhao basically, I'm trying to find all the participants who didn't make an effort (i.e. completed at least one response).

Comment: @minigeek Thanks! I looked up what the HAVING keyword was and found this: "The HAVING clause was added to SQL because the WHERE keyword could not be used with aggregate functions". Yup, pretty much covers it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use conditional counting to count the number of incomplete responses and compare it with the total number of responses. Filtering on aggregate functions must be done in the `having` clause.

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM participants p
LEFT JOIN responses r 
  ON p.id = r.id_participant
GROUP BY p.id  --depending on mysql version you may have to list all fields from p here
HAVING count(*)=0 
  OR count(*)=1 
 AND count(IF(r.ended IS NULL, 1, NULL))=1
```

Comment: This parses and executes without error .. and on first glance is producing results that look right. I'll dig deeper thru the data to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure following query does work for you, but try it：

```
SELECT p.*
FROM participants p
LEFT JOIN responses r ON p.id = r.id_participant
WHERE r.id IS NULL -- this will fetch participant with no response
OR EXISTS ( -- here will fetch participant with one incompleted response.
    SELECT 1
    FROM responses
    WHERE p.id = responses.id_participant
    GROUP BY responses.id_participant
    HAVING SUM(responses.ended IS NULL) = COUNT(1) AND COUNT(1) = 1
)
```